# Is a system of ODEs solvable if the coefficient matrix has determinant zero?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Pardon the simple question, but my memory's failing me on this, and I can't seem to find any answers.

I have a system of differential equations, with a coefficient matrix that looks like this, where a, b, and c are constants:

\begin{bmatrix}
 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\ 
 0& 0&-a& 0& b& 0\\ 
 0& a& 0& 0& 0& c\\ 
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\ 
 0& 0& 0&-1& 0&-a\\ 
 0& 0& 0& 0& a& 0
\end{bmatrix}

Now, it's pretty obvious to see that the coefficient matrix has a zero determinant (expand over the first column).  Does this mean that the system is unsolvable?  If so, what can I do to make it solvable?

Comment: You can solve the equation $\dot{x} = 0$, right?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood That's exactly the type of basic intuition I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ODE system $\dot x = Ax$ has always the solution 
$$
x(t)=\exp(tA)x_0=x_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}A^kx_0
$$
and the series always converges as it is dominated by $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{|t|^k}{k!}\|A\|^k\|x_0\|=e^{|t|\,\|A\|}\|x_0\|$. There is no admissibility restriction on the matrix $A$.

Comment: This answer seems supposed on having a non-zero initial condition for the system.  If I had a set of boundary conditions such that x1(0)=x3(0)=x5(0) = x1(L)=x3(L)=x5(L) = 0, do you think that would change?

Comment: Going back to Daniel Littlewood's hint above:  Can you solve $\dot{x}_1 = 0, \dot{x}_2 = 3 x_2$ given the boundary conditions $x_1(0) = x_1(L) = 0$?  How about $x_1(0) = 0, x_1(L) = 1$?

Comment: I think you got your subscripts messed up, but I think I get it.  The homogeneous system is always solvable, it's just a matter of whether or not it is trivial.